# mvc3 ajax submission on the controller side. How?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I don't understand once button clicked

**How to handle ajax call on the server side so that my DataAnnotation work
and I get success or error message.**

```
<script src="../../../../Content/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(function () 
     {
         $("#createButton").click(function () 
         {
             var profile = {
                 FirstName: $("#FirstName").val(),
                 LastName: $("#LastName").val(),
                 Email: $("#Email").val()
             };

                 $.ajax({
                     url: "/Profile/Create",
                     type: "Post",
                     data: JSON.stringyfy(profile),
                     dataType: "json",
                     contentType: "Application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     success: function () {
                         $("#message").html("Profile Saved.");
                     },
                     error: function () {
                         $("#message").html("Error occured");
                     }
                 });

            return false;
        });
     });

</script>

//Server side
public ActionResult Create(string confirmButton, CreateViewModel userVm)
{
    if (confirmButton != "Create Profile") return RedirectToAction("Index");

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View("Create", userVm);

    User user = new User();
    Mapper.Map(userVm, user);

    _repository.Create(user);

    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = user.UserId });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly (it's been a while since I played with jquery), the success and error are indicative of the return value of the actual HTTP request itself. For example, if you hit a 404, you'd get an error message.

Regardless of whether or not a profile was created successfully through your page logic, if the request itself was processed, then the success message will be hit - you need to interpret the return value yourself at that point.

Comment: I understand. But like in the above controller code what I return once validation fail. Instead of return View("Create", userVm); what should I return. Thats the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a JsorResult in place of redirecting to a view, then client side, parse the JsonResult and act accordingly.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteDoc(int Id, int DocCode, SomeObject Model) 
{    
try
{
    // Check annotations stuffs
    if (!Model.IsValid) {
    var jsonDataM = new { ExitCode= -100, message = "Invalid Model" };
    return Json(jsonDataM, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
    // My logic in here
    var jsonData = new { ExitCode= 0, message = "Everything's ok" };
    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    var jsonData2 = new { ExitCode= -1, message = "Everything's Ko" + e.Message };
    return Json(jsonDat2a, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
} 
}
```

in the OnSuccess callback you can refer to this with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MyAjaxCallBack(context) {
  var code = context.ExitCode;
  if (code != 0) {
    alert (context.message);
  }
}
</script>
```

Please note that this code is simplified. When managing the IsValid on Model, I usually iterate del ModelState in order to build up a message.